# How to defined filter expression to filter nested json array based on object key value in aws app sync query filter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have the following filter conditions to be for filtering `studentBookmark` json array based on value of JSON key. I want to know how to filter the queried data based on object value key from JSON array.

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        ## Provide a query expression. **
        "expression": "studentId = :id",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":id" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.identity.username)
        }
    },
    "filter" : {
        ## --- issue here for studentBookmarks -- Need help ----
        "expression": "isBookmarked = :isBookmarked OR studentBookmarks.studentId = :studentId",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":isBookmarked" : { "BOOL": true },
            ":studentId": { "S": "${ctx.identity.username}" },
        },
    },
    "index": "studentId-index",
}
```

I want to know what proper expression to be given to filter based nested json array.

Comment: What does your ddb table look like? Does it actually have an attribute named `studentBookmarks.studentId`? Is this a nested attribute?

Comment: It has an attribute `studentBookmarks` which is array of json object with `studentId` being a property of the object.

Comment: Looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html#Expressions.Attributes.NestedAttributes), you can use a dot access for map elements. and you use [n] for list elements